# AWS Rekognition throwing error: InvalidS3ObjectException

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have set a lambda to be triggered when a video file is uploaded into a s3 bucket. This lambda calls the rekognition API (lambda is in python).

I generate a pre-signed url to upload the file into the bucket.

When I upload a file from postman using the url, the file goes into the bucket, the lambda is called, and start_label_detection() works fine.

However if I try to upload the file from a function in a python django server I am working on, the file goes into the bucket, the lambda is called and this exception:

```
[ERROR] InvalidS3ObjectException: An error occurred (InvalidS3ObjectException) when calling the StartLabelDetection operation: Unable to get object metadata from S3. Check object key, region and/or access permissions.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 19, in lambda_handler
    MinConfidence=75,
  File "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 316, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 635, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
```

The first half of the lambda:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    key = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']
    
    if key[-4:] != '.mp4':
        return 'Not mp4'
    
    rekognition = boto3.client('rekognition')
    transcribe = boto3.client('transcribe')
    sns = boto3.client('sns')
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    
    rekog_response = rekognition.start_label_detection(
        Video={'S3Object': {'Bucket': 'rekog-video-bucket', 'Name': key}},
        MinConfidence=75,
    )
```

The command to upload into the bucket: (the same upload works from postman no problem)

```
response = requests.put(put_url, data=f.read())
```

The IAM role has full access to the s3 and rekog. I don't know why it could possibly make a difference here.